# Binding selected value from mat-select form to be passed to submit button function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design, formbuilder

Updated in reference to German's answer

I am trying to pass the instrumentName field from the instrument value selected by the user to the function in the submit button. The instrumentName value shows up properly, but it never seems to be saved upon submitting. All of the other input values save fine. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
      <form [formGroup]="createForm" class="create-form">

        </mat-form-field -->
        <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
            <mat-label>Instrument</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput formControlName="createForm.get('Machine_ID')" #Machine_ID>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let instrument of instruments" [value]="instrument.instrumentName">
                    {{instrument.instrumentName}}
                  </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/list">Back</button>&nbsp;
        <button  (click)="addSample()"
          [disabled]="createForm.invalid"  color="primary">Save</button>
      </form>
```

TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FileService } from '../../file.service';
import { Instrument } from '../../instrument.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-sample',
  templateUrl: './add-new-sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-sample.component.css']
})
export class AddNewSampleComponent implements OnInit {
  createForm: FormGroup;
  instruments: Instrument[];
  constructor(private fileService: FileService, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
    this.createForm = this.fb.group({

      Machine_ID: '',

    });

    }
    addSample() {
      const machineIdValue = this.createForm.get('Machine_ID').value;
      this.fileService.addSample(machineIdValue).subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/instruments']);
      });
    }
    fetchInstruments(){
      this.fileService.getInstruments()
      .subscribe((data: Instrument[])=>
      {
        this.instruments = data;

      })
    }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchInstruments();
  }

}
```

Comment: What function are you invoking when you click onSubmit button?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it in, it sends the data to the "addSample(Machine_ID)" function on click.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the Machine_ID reference through the template. 
You can call the formGroup and get the `Machine_ID` formControl value like this:

`this.createForm.get('Machine_ID').value`

So in `addSample` you can do:

```
addSample(/*other inputs*/) {
  const machineIdValue = this.createForm.get('Machine_ID').value;
  this.fileService.addSample(/*other inputs*/, machineIdValue).subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/instruments']);
  });
}
```

Then you should update your submit button:

```
<form [formGroup]="createForm" class="create-form">
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
            <mat-label>Instrument</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput formControlName="createForm.get('Machine_ID')" #Machine_ID>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let instrument of instruments" [value]="instrument.instrumentName">
                    {{instrument.instrumentName}}
                  </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button (click)="addSample()"
          [disabled]="createForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: When I do this and make the appropriate adjustments to the addSample arguments in the html and ts code, the submit button no longer functions.

Comment: There I updated my answer and I change the submit botton

Comment: Yes, that's how I updated my submit button, but it just doesn't do anything now

Comment: Try removing the ```mat-raised-button``` property

Comment: I think I figure out the error, it's the formControlName in the mat-select. To reference the formControl 'Machine_ID' you have to do: ```formControlName =createForm.get('Machine_ID')```. There I update my answer

Comment: This still does not work. The code is the exact same as above in your answer (i removed my other inputs temporarily).

Comment: It seems only the instrument object, and not instrument.instrumentName can be passed to the [value] element, which doesn't make any sense to me, since instrument.instrumentName is a valid property of instrument which can be viewed in the list... Either way, just passing the entire instrument property will work for me. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Your welcome, great to hear that you can fix the issue.